# dll error / mysterious system crashes

Tags: windows, crash

I bought my mom this cheap dell for use in her kitchen. She literally does nothing but facebook games, youtube, and email on this computer.
She keeps getting an error about:
api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll

The only problem, is that the error message appears and then within a few seconds the entire system just shuts down. So I'm not sure if its missing this .dll, or what specifically the issue is. There is nothing particularly wrong with the computer except that sometimes it just randomly displays this message then shuts down.

Is there an easy fix? Or should I just wipe the drive and reinstall windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went ahead and installed Ubuntu 12.04 on the system.

Comment: try http://superuser.com/, since SO is for programming questions